# how can i change column when the other table column changed?

Tags: mysql

i create database named 'DB'. and make schema like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWEbI.png)

- Table themes has 3 colors each rows.
- Table Highlights is used to save text highlighting from colorHex.
- Table pages has pageUrl which contain Highlights.text
- we can only choose color from theme table(color1, color2, color3). so Table users remember themeId

now i wondering, how can i changed highlights.colors when users.themeId is changed?

example)

Table users

| userId | name | themeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | name1 | theme1 |
| user2 | name2 | theme2 |

Table themes

| themeId | color1 | color2 | color3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| theme1 | red | blue | green |
| theme2 | black | silver | gold |

Table highlights

| highlightId | colorHex | text | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| high1 | red | anyText1 | user1 |
| high2 | black | anyText2 | user2 |

===================================================

in this situation, when users row1's theme1 changes theme2,
row high1ights row1's color changed red to black

| userId | name | themeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | name1 | **theme2** |
| user2 | name2 | theme2 |

Table themes

| themeId | color1 | color2 | color3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| theme1 | red | blue | green |
| **theme2** | black | silver | gold |

Table highlights

| highlightId | colorHex | text | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| high1 | **black** | anyText1 | user1 |
| high2 | black | anyText2 | user2 |

---

highlights.colorHex value must be one of the themes.colors

when users.themeId changes, highlights.colorHex also changes color which The value of the nth column of the new table at the same position as the nth column of the previous table

thanks for reading my poor descriptions, and Please give me a clue to solving the problem

Comment: I'm lost in your tables and their function but it doesn't make me sense to change `colorHex` when user change his theme. It looks like duplicated value which is saved in other tables. You can work with `theme.color1` directly without resaving this value to another table.

Comment: I echo Pavel's confusion, and note that if you need to do something like that, it implies that your table structures are improper and you should redesign them. There should be no reason to change something in one table because you changed something in another. I recommend you research "database normalization."

Comment: thanks for informations. i will consider new schema, and find about normalization